# Angular 4 Lazy Loading SEO-behavior

Tags: seo, lazyloading, angular

I have an application developed in Angular 4, which previously had the information of the keywords in the main module of the application (Before implementing the lazy loading), which appeared on the first page of the google search results. However, later for performance reasons, I implemented lazy loading in my application and moved the content of the keywords to a lazy loading module, after this change my page does not appear in the google search results (it is neither in the first 100 under the same search terms used before). Finally, from the google search console, all the pages that contain keywords are indexed, since I do it through the google search console and they appear green (indexed) I do this contextualization to ask the following question:

Why did implementing the lazy load in my application change the SEO-behavior of my page if before this change (When lazy loading was not implemented) the page was shown among the first search results?

This causes me some confusion and doubts, since without the implementation of lazy loading I had good results in SEO despite the fact that my application was not under Angular Universal as many recommend, which makes me think about the current state of the art of the search engines respect the pages purely made with javascript, in the style of angular

Many Thaks!

Comment: From what I can tell from a bit of reading, lazy loading in Angular 4 is a technique to only load the home page of the web app until a user clicks to a different page at which point the new page will load.    Is that accurate?   Are you having SEO problems with your home page, with other pages, or with both?

Comment: I have problems with the pages that contains the keywords, which are under the lazy loading modules, since the main page will obviously never be under lazy loading. Thanks!

Comment: When you visit the URL of one of these deep pages directly what happens?  Does that deep page show up without user interaction?  Is it still lazy loaded?

Comment: When I visit the URL of the deep page “opusclick.com/servicios/plomero” the page loads without problems... this deep page are under lazy load module